# Bullet gem not logging from Rails console

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the Bullet gem to profile some mySql queries.  in config/environments/development.rb, I enable it:

```
config.after_initialize do
  Bullet.enable = true
  Bullet.bullet_logger = true
  Bullet.rails_logger = true
  Bullet.raise = true
end
```

I then run a simple import command from the console:

```
Item.import_file "import/file1.txt"
```

log/bullet.log is empty.  I see all of the mysql queries go by in the console, just no output.  Does bullet work in the Rails console?  If so, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Are you DEFINITELY using N+1 queries? Sounds like bullet could well be working fine, but it just doesn't see anything in your import that it needs to notify you about.

Comment: (There's no reason why bullet shouldn't work in the rails console, btw)

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to call Bullet.profile:

```rb
  Bullet.profile { User.first.as_json } # or something
```